# can IcedTea's Pulse Audio implementation of Java Sound be taken from OpenJDK and run on Sun Java

Tags: audio, java, pulseaudio

I have found Sun's implementation of JSAPI on Linux to be beyond awful. To put it mildly. The Pulse Audio implementation, courtesy of IcedTea, has some quirks but offers much better performance overall. My only problem is that I don't want to force end-users to install another JRE on my app's behalf. Is there any feasible way to extract and package the OpenJDK implementation for use elsewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](http://www.mail-archive.com/universe-bugs@lists.ubuntu.com/msg146425.html) is a reference in an Ubuntu bug report to using the OpenJDK Pulse Audio implementation with the Sun JDK. I have not done it myself so cannot confirm if it works.